# What is the name of the region between two concentric arcs with the same central angle?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I am wondering what the name for a section of the area between two concentric circles is called?  It's essentially an isosceles trapezoid with the "parallel" sides now curved.  I have Googled different iterations of "rounded trapezoid" and "2D toroidal section" etc., but have not found a term that I feel suits this shape.

I appreciate everyone's help.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it has a known name. If you need one for something you are writing, make one up and tell your reader. "Angular section of an annulus" might do.

Comment: It isn't a complete annulus, but part of one?

Comment: annulus sector? This is how the wiki entry of [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29) call it.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing an academic journal paper and some of these terms are out of my wheelhouse.  I appreciate the recommendation of defining my term for the reader.  I just want to make sure I'm not making up a name for it if a name already exists.  Imagine dancing around the word "triangle", haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a shape is sometimes referred to as a *truncated sector* or an *annular sector*. [Here is a link](https://www.google.com/search?q=truncated%20sector&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS784US784&oq=truncated%20sector&aqs=chrome..69i57.3591j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to google search results showing the use of the term "truncated sector."

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts it's also called a "Polar Rectangle" since it is the region $(r_0 \leq r \leq r_1) \times (\theta_0 \leq \theta \leq \theta_1)$. That is, it's the product of two polar intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but annular wedge makes sense, as it is to a circular wedge what an annulus is to a circle

Answer (score 0):

The area between two concentric circles is called: *an annulus*.
So you can call the blue part: *a sector of an annulus*.